# oracle generate multiple xml file the file like inv_no1.xml ,inv_no2.xml inv_no3.xml

Tags: xml, oracle

need to generate multiple xml file with rename the file

this my code this work on sample hr select schema  for example select * from employees
when i put my tables not working  and the issue ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processin
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 176

if i have table have inv
inv_no
inv_date
qty
price
i need to select only one invoice and convert to xml 1 file with name file
inv_no1.xml
inv_no2.xml
and make input parameter for date .when i put the date will get all inv in that day in multi xml file

Comment: You need to edit your question and 1) show the complete table DDL formatted, 2) sample data, 3) expected output.

Comment: Although it's hard to know without the source code, the most common error that causes "command not properly ended" errors is including the semicolon at the end. The semicolon is not needed in a dynamic SQL context.